# Why will :after be drawed strangely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```
.specific_tag_cases a:after{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: white;
    content: "×";
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Ok, all fine.

---

But sometimes suddenly it appears like this after page reloading:

[image]

There isn't any specific logic in the behind of it. I mean I don't know when exactly it will be drawed strangely. Anytime it can occur.

Why? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you.

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue to me, are you sure all the pages that use it are UTF-8?

Comment: @Terry Yes, I've this *meta* code in the `<head>` of the page: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. Also as I've mentioned, it's usually ok. Just sometimes appears wrong.

Comment: Downvote why please explain if OP's upvoted

Comment: Hmmm, that’s very strange indeed!

Comment: @Terry please wait for OP's comments, then downvote if Op's comments goes with you.

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted you? Don’t jump to conclusions. We are all here to help.

Comment: Yes that's i am saying we are here to help not for lying and mind your language what did you mean by jump. i posted an answer and you downvoted and then comment to OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define `height` and `width` for `a` tag.

You are using `border-radius:50%;` but you don't assign a `width` and `height`, And if you need a rounded box you have to assign equal `width` and `height`.

like below

```
.specific_tag_cases a:after{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: white;
    content: "×";
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:8px;  /*Add this*/
    height:8px; /*Add this*/
}
```

Working example included. In this example i removed `position` and change `margin` property, because i don't need it.

```css
a {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  color: white;
  content: "×";
  padding: 0px 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px; /*I changed margin-right to left*/
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

Comment: I've added both `height` and `width` properties. It's ok by now, I hope it be ok forever. thank you, upvote

Comment: Ok, the problem happened again. But thanks your approach, the size of the circle doesn't change anymore `:-)`, just its content changes.

Comment: You are using a `x`  so change it english `x` not special character  i posted example use it `content` part  may be it will help,