# Why multiplication sign will be converted to strange characters?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I'm use *[multiplication sign `×`](http://graphemica.com/%C3%97)* in the CSS codes like this:

```
.specific_tag_cases a:after{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: white;
    content: "×";
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:13px; 
    height:12px; 
}
```

But the content will be replaced with this after page reloading:

```
    content: "Ã—";
```

How can I avoid this odd behavior?

Comment: Seems fine to me https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YQaVpW does it happen in a particular browser? maybe you have some other stuff on your page/site that's modifying it?

Comment: Downvoter, what's wrong with my question? Please leave a comment and explain the reason.

Comment: try using this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/awYWBe

Comment: @MichaelCoker It seems fine in the fiddle you provided. It's also fine for me in the most of times. Just that strange encoding will be happened sometimes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859106/why-will-after-be-drawed-strangely

Comment: @MichaelCoker Oh, I was missing your point. Yes using `\00D7` instead of `×` is a great idea. thank you

Comment: You bet. Did that help? If so I can submit as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes. Go ahead please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off using the escaped unicode version of it in a css `content` property.

The value for the multiplication symbol is `\00D7`

```css
.specific_tag_cases a:after{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: white;
    content: "\00D7";
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:13px; 
    height:12px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="specific_tag_cases">
  <a>link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your CSS file needs to be encoded in UTF-8
- Your HTML file needs to be encoded in UTF-8
- Your HTML needs to be served as UTF-8

```css
.fman a:after {
    content: "×";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test "×"</title>
</head>
<body class="fman">
<a href="#">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case, it looks like the [`×`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) is encoded as UTF-8, i.e. `0xc3`, `0x97` but is being interpreted as [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set) in your browser:

> Ã 195 (`0xc3`)

and

> — 151 (`0x97`)

You can omit `<meta charset="utf-8">` if your server is correctly configured to serve UTF-8 encoded documents as UTF-8 encoded, but if wrong or no information is provided, browsers will either try to guess or apply a default.

Comment: Yes, your code looks right to me. My code also is right in the most of times. Just that strange encoding will be happened sometimes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859106/why-will-after-be-drawed-strangely

Comment: Well honestly I didn't get the solution? should I remove that `meta` tag? Just that?

Comment: Of course you should **not** remove the meta tag. You should make sure that the encoding of the HTML document matches the meta tag and the HTTP header information provided by the server. Also, make sure your CSS is being served as UTF-8.